# SSRS Server Data Sources Lost authentication

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using sql 2016 Ent. and had a very strange issue yesterday. I had most of my shared data sources on my production ssrs server suddenly "lose" their authentication to their sql servers. The fix was to go to each one by one and re-enter their password values to reset them. 
Has anyone seen this type of behavior before? the servers are windows server 2016 clustered in an active/passive mode. the SSRS service is active on both nodes.

Comment: Probably a candidate for research on https://dba.stackexchange.com/. Not really on topic for SO.

Comment: It sounds like someone deployed the reports after including them in a new VS project or moved the reports to another report folder. There are certain actions performed during development that will cause the ssrs to remove data source passwords. There is no warning and someone could have deployed not knowing the passwords would be removed during deployment.